# Reproducir sonido python-arduino

Tags: python, arduino

Tengo que hacer un proyecto de la escuela. Se trata de un reproductor de música en Python que controle con un modulo receptor infrarrojo, que se conecta con Arduino.

El problema es que con botones en tkinter funciona muy bien pero al correr con Arduino no funciona, no reproduce ningún sonido, ni siquiera entra al método que requiero,ya he intentando de varias maneras y no se que mas hacer, esto tengo hasta ahora

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import serial
import time
from time import  sleep
global aux
aux=0


ini=tk.Tk()
ini.geometry("490x500")
ini.title("Reproductor de musica ITC")
ini.config(bg='gray')
pygame.mixer.init()

def agregar():
    canciones=filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/",title="Elige una cancion",filetypes=(("mp3",".mp3"),("all files",".*")))
    for cancion in canciones:
        cancion=cancion.replace("E:\Sexto Semestre\Programacion Avanzada\Parcial 4\musica","")
        cancion=cancion.replace(".mp3","")
        pantalla.insert(END,cancion)

def play():
    cancion=pantalla.get(ACTIVE)
    cancion=f'{cancion}.mp3'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(cancion)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)

def stop():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pantalla.selection_clear(ACTIVE)

def siguiente():
    proxima=pantalla.curselection()
    proxima=proxima[0]+1
    cancion=pantalla.get(proxima)
    cancion=f'{cancion}.mp3'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(cancion)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pantalla.selection_clear(0,END)
    pantalla.activate(proxima)
    last=None
    pantalla.selection_set(proxima,last)

def anterior():
    proxima=pantalla.curselection()
    proxima=proxima[0]-1
    cancion=pantalla.get(proxima)
    cancion=f'{cancion}.mp3'
    pygame.mixer.music.load(cancion)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=0)
    pantalla.selection_clear(0,END)
    pantalla.activate(proxima)
    last=None
    pantalla.selection_set(proxima,last)
global paused
paused=False
def pause (is_paused):
    global paused
    paused=is_paused
    if paused:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        paused=False
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        paused=True
def borrar1():
    pantalla.delete(ANCHOR)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

def borrar_todas():
    pantalla.delete(0,END)
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

def mas():
    volume=pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
    print(volume)
    if (volume<1):
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume+.1)
def menos():
    volume=pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()
    print(volume)
    if (volume>0):
        pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume-.1)

def cerrar():
    ini.destroy()
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    #pantalla.selection_clear(ACTIVE)
    arduino.close()
    
arduino=serial.Serial("COM3",9600)
time.sleep(2)
def leervalor():
    arduino.flushInput()
    lectura=arduino.readline()
    valor=(lectura.decode())
    print(valor)
    if(valor=="PAUSE"):
        play()
                    #if(valor==2):
        
    if(valor=="FAST FORWARD"):
        siguiente()
    if(valor=="FAST BACK"):
        anterior()
  
    if(valor=="VOL+"):
        mas()
    if(lectura=="VOL-"):
        menos()

pantalla=Listbox(ini,bg='black',fg='white',width=60,selectbackground='white',selectforeground='black')
pantalla.place(x=55,y=20)

#anterior=Button(ini,text="Anterior",command=anterior)
#anterior.place(x=70,y=450)

reproducir=Button(ini,text="Reproducir",command=leervalor)
reproducir.place(x=125,y=450)


dell=Button(ini, text="I/O", command=cerrar)
dell.place(x=460,y=0)

menubar=Menu(ini)
ini.config(menu=menubar)
agregar_cancion=Menu(menubar)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Agregar cancion",menu=agregar_cancion)
agregar_cancion.add_command(label="Agregar una o mas canciones a la lista", command=agregar)
```

espero puedan ayudarme por favor

Comment: Hola Angelica. Bienvenida a StackOverflow, no entiendo muy bien lo que tratas de hacer. Te pido que por favor expliques mejor como quieres que interactúe python con el arduino, y tambien que coloques el codigo de arduino que estas usando, y finalmente que quites ese monton de "aaaa..." que no ayudan en nada a la pregunta, y que podrian alejar a las personas que te pueden ayudar

Comment: No veo ningún código para Arduino. Tendrías que tener un Arduino + Shield MP3 para reproducir música. Faltan esos detalles, así como el diagrama de conexión.